# Excel - combine UNIQUE formula reference with text string

Tags: excel, unique

I'm trying to create a dropdown list in Excel based on my source data by using the UNIQUE function, like say column "Team" has Team01-Team10 which is fetched with `=UNIQUE(table[teams])`, and then I want to add an asterisk to that list and still be able to use it dynamically for a data validation list. Like I can when I only have the original values by referencing A1# (if we say the formula is in A1). Does someone have a creative solution for this?

I have tried combining cell reference and the string `*` in data validation, which does not work. I have also tried putting the formula in A2 instead, and then writing the asterisk `*` in A1 and creating a named range, referencing A1:A2#, which basically throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TEXTJOIN and FILTERXML to create an array with the `*`.

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>*</b><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,UNIQUE(table[teams]))&"</b></a>","//b")
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! My example was simplified, so in reality I managed to get another workaround too: In reality I have Type, Site, Channel and Team headers in A1-D1. Under those I wanted dropdown lists. The team names in my data are "Type_Site_Channel_Team", so what I did in Cell F1 was to write: 
```=UNIQUE(FILTER(raw[Team],ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2&"*"&B2&"*"&C2&"*"&D2,raw[Team]))))``` and then in H1-K1 I wrote same titles and in H2-K2 I used this formula: ```UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F1#,"_",REPT(" ",LEN(F1#))), (1-1)*LEN(F1#)+1, LEN(G4#))))``` where (1-1)  targets "Type", (2-1) for Site and so on

Comment: ..in the original source data team column that was "Type_Site_Channel_Team", and finally I could reference H2#, I2#, J2# and K2# in data validation in A2-D2.. ending up with a pivot table for team names basically (only quirk being that since its all dynamic, I have to press DELETE on the value to reset the dropdowns). Your solution was more elegant though! Thanks!

Comment: How would I also add something after the range? Sorry, I am not very well versed in XML

Comment: replace `&"</b></a>"` with `&"<b>yourNewItem</b></a>"` @Strechingmycompetence

Comment: So ```=FILTERXML("<a><b>*</b><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,UNIQUE(table[teams]))&"<b>yourNewItem</b></a>","//b")```? That gave me #Value

Comment: should there perhaps be a C-element?

Comment: sorry: `=FILTERXML("<a><b>*</b><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,UNIQUE(table[teams]))&"</b><b>yourNewItem</b></a>","//b")`

Comment: Figured it out ```"<b>yourNewItem</b></b></a>"```

Comment: Haha, thanks! :D Found a new use for this! Building a webpage based on the agents now, so the * is replaced with the start of the htm document until the first repeated element, then the yourNewItem part will be the code after the last element, and all rows in between will simply be a concatenation of the html for the repeated element. So when I import a table of the agents, then I can simply just copy the result column into a text document and save as .htm with an updated list :D

Comment: ..and it didn't work. It will work to concatenate any text, but HTML tags will ruin it -_-

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i don't understand your question, i just look at the answer of @Scott Craner, 
please forgive me if I am wrong, here is my formula:

```
=UNIQUE(IF(ISERROR(1/(ROW(1:6)-1)),"*",C2:C7))
```

[image]